# Как правильно сделать merge

Tags: git, git-merge

У меня вот так получились, что при слиянии ветки в мастер я получил конфликт. Я его пофиксил(мне так показалось) , но в итоге вообще все поламалось.

Я нашел последний нормальный коммит сделал от него ветку, допилил до нужного состояния и вот теперь она выглядит ровно так как мне нужно.

Теперь вопрос, у меня есть две ветки, одна мастер и вторая test

Мастер после мержа лежит поломанная и test которую я собрал заново.

Как теперь мне сделать мерж, чтоб мастер полностью забрал ветку test и не показывал мне конфликты?

Можно как то просто сказать, что теперь master будет test? Передвинуть указатель или что то в этом роде?

Comment: По идее если всё в мастере после коммита, от которого вышел test не нужно, то можно сбросить (reset) мастер до этого коммита и спокойно вмержить test

Comment: @ЮрийСПб То есть если я правильно понял, нужно переключиться на мастера, сделать git reset и указать хэш коммита до которого я хочу опуститься(в моем случае 7a96752) и тогда замержить ветку test в мастер, так?

Comment: можно просто подвинуть указатель мастера на тест `git branch -f master test`. Но это есть смысл делать только в том случае, если репозиторий в Вашем монопольном владении или ветка test есть наследником origin/master

Comment: @KoVadim да но тогда ветка так и будет продолжатся называться test. Тогда нужно будет удалить master(кстати я не уверен, что гид не защищает эту ветку) и потом переименовать  test в мастер, так?

Comment: в гите у веток нет имени. А ветка - это просто указатель на коммит.  Поэтому, новая "ветка" будет одновременно и test, и master

Comment: @KoVadim ну это да, но у меня то локально она называется test.... А мне нравиться, чтоб она называлась master

Comment: `git branch -f master test && git branch -D test`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, тут можно поступить так:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard commitName1
git merge test
```

где commitName1 - название того коммита из которого вы начали ветку test. Ветка master сольется с test.

Если в какой-то момент вы поняли, что закоммители плохой, ненужный или поломанный коммит, вы всегда можете сделать `git reset --hard stableCommitName`. Также важно помнить, что `git reset --hard` Переводит вашу ветку в указанное состояние, а все более новые изменения стираются. Чтобы обезапасить себя от потери чего-то нужного можно делать так:

```
git checkout master
git reset --soft commitName1
git stash
git merge test
```

эффект будет похожий, только более поздние изменения сохранятся в stash. Чтобы их вернуть, достаточно сделать `git stash apply`. И наконец, если вы потеряли коммит после `reset --hard` или `rebase` или еще как-нибудь, то его номер и название наверняка можно найти, сделав `git reflog`.

Comment: Разве первое не равносильно `git checkout master; git reset --hard test` ?